# Connecting through two putty sessions

Tags: putty

I'm using the last putty version and can't create two different sessions (Needed when I need to do SSH TUNNELING and log the server for maintanance)

Here is the log from the second connection that got failed:

```
Looking up host "[IP]"
Connecting to [IP] port 22
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Snapshot_2011_04_14:r9149
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1-hpn13v11
Using SSH protocol version 2
Server supports delayed compression; will try this later
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
```

Then it hangs.
It happens only with putty. I can log on with OpenSSH client (through linux) with any number of sessions that I want.

Comment: What do you mean by '2 different sessions' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to open a session from computer A to B with a tunnel. Then another from B to C, again with a tunnel, and thinking it's easy to get the data to traverse the two tunnels. This is not easy and I wouldn't recommend it at all.

You can however, open A to B with a tunnel and use that tunnel to open a connection from A to C. This second connection can then easily tunnel whatever you want from C back to A.